# Displaying values from a private int in c#

Tags: c#, private, public

Here is the code

I can´t get the limit counter to increment for each time
I can get it to count to 1 between each outputline, but that´s it
Any idea why?
I want it to be able to count every "overshoot"

```
class Actuator
{
    private int limit_count = 0;

    public int Inc_Limit_counter(int temp,int co2_conc,int rel_humid)
    {
        if(temp > 70 || co2_conc > 450 || rel_humid > 77)
            limit_count++;

        //Console.WriteLine("test {0}",limit_count);
         return limit_count;
    }

    public int Get_limit_count()
    {
        return limit_count;
    }
}


class Program
{
    static int read_random_values()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int temp, co2_conc, rel_humid, i;

        Console.WriteLine("Temperature in celcius:");
        for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            temp = r.Next(-50,50);
            co2_conc = r.Next(300,600);
            rel_humid = r.Next(0,100);

            Console.WriteLine("The temperature is: {0}, Co2 concentration is: {1} and Relative Humidity is: {2}",temp,co2_conc,rel_humid);

            Actuator Counter1 = new Actuator();
            Counter1.Inc_Limit_counter(temp, co2_conc, rel_humid);     
        }

        return 0;
    }


    static void Main()
    {
        read_random_values();
        Actuator object1 = new Actuator();
        object1.Get_limit_count();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that you are creating a new instance of the Actuator class each time you call the Inc Method. So your counter will be increased one time and then the object is not used any more. I think you are missing the static Keywords for the counter and the two Methods of the Actuator class.

Answer (score 0):

First: In your Main method you create a new Actuator instance and read its value.  When you create a new Actuator, the limit_count field will be initialized to 0.

Second: In your read_random_values method, you keep creating new Actuators inside the for loop.  Each time you do this, you have a new Actuator with a limit_count of zero.

Third: In your Main method, you are calling Get_limit_count(object1).  Get_limit_count doesn't take a parameter and should be called like this object1.Get_limit_count.

Try these changes:

```
static void Main()
{
    Actuator object1 = new Actuator();
    read_random_values(object1);

    Console.WriteLine("Final limit count: " + object1.Get_limit_count()); //Get_limit_count doesn't take a parameter and is called like this.
}

static int read_random_values(Actuator actuator)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int temp, co2_conc, rel_humid, i;


  Console.WriteLine("Temperature in celcius:");
  for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
  {
     temp = r.Next(-50,50);
     co2_conc = r.Next(300,600);
     rel_humid = r.Next(0,100);



    Console.WriteLine("The temperature is: {0}, Co2 concentration is: {1} and Relative Humidity is: {2}",temp,co2_conc,rel_humid);

    actuator.Inc_Limit_counter(temp, co2_conc, rel_humid);     

  }
}
```

As a side note, consider looking into style guides for naming conventions.  Typically in C# methods start with a capital letter and each new word is capitilized, e.g. ReadRandomValues.  Not read_random_values.